# Android - Switch ActionBar Back Button to Navigation Button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, back-button

I am having the following problem:

I know how to set up a toolbar to show a back button icon instead of a burger button icon.

From this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

using: `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Now, I want to do the reverse action, I want to go from back button icon to burger icon:

[image]

to here:

[image]

How can I do this?

**Update:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
}

private void enableViews(boolean enable) {
    if(enable) {
        // Enables back button icon
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    } else {
        // TODO: Enables burger icon
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/28072236/1607191

Answer (score 137, accepted):

If I assume you're using `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` in your layout, then this approach may work for you; I've only tested on `API 21` but given it's mostly using the support libraries, it *should* work (famous last words) on lower or higher targets.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private boolean mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        // Get DrawerLayout ref from layout
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        // Initialize ActionBarDrawerToggle, which will control toggle of hamburger.
        // You set the values of R.string.open and R.string.close accordingly.
        // Also, you can implement drawer toggle listener if you want.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle (this, drawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        // Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        // Calling sync state is necessary to show your hamburger icon...
        // or so I hear. Doesn't hurt including it even if you find it works
        // without it on your test device(s)
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    /**
     * To be semantically or contextually correct, maybe change the name
     * and signature of this function to something like:
     *
     * private void showBackButton(boolean show)
     * Just a suggestion.
     */
     private void enableViews(boolean enable) {

        // To keep states of ActionBar and ActionBarDrawerToggle synchronized,
        // when you enable on one, you disable on the other.
        // And as you may notice, the order for this operation is disable first, then enable - VERY VERY IMPORTANT.
        if(enable) {
            //You may not want to open the drawer on swipe from the left in this case  
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
            // Remove hamburger
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
            // Show back button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // when DrawerToggle is disabled i.e. setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false), navigation icon
            // clicks are disabled i.e. the UP button will not work.
            // We need to add a listener, as in below, so DrawerToggle will forward
            // click events to this listener.
            if(!mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered) {
                mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // Doesn't have to be onBackPressed
                        onBackPressed();
                    }
                });

                mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered = true;
            }

        } else {
            //You must regain the power of swipe for the drawer. 
            drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);

            // Remove back button
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            // Show hamburger 
            mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
            // Remove the/any drawer toggle listener
            mDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(null);
            mToolBarNavigationListenerIsRegistered = false;
        }

        // So, one may think "Hmm why not simplify to:
        // .....
        // getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(enable);
        // mDrawer.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(!enable);
        // ......
        // To re-iterate, the order in which you enable and disable views IS important #dontSimplify.
    }
```

The solution uses `ActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled` to toggle the visibility of the hamburger icon and `ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` for visibility of the *Up* button, essentially making use of their respective `drawable` resources.

**Other assumptions**

- Your Activity theme extends `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Comment: Amazing, @Ade.Akinyede! It was exactly I was looking for. You fulfilled all my bounty requirements, gave a good explanation and a good example, also you did a good analysis and suggestions. You earned the bounty

Comment: Glad to hear it :)

Comment: @ade.akinyede Thank you for the answer, my follow up question is that how could I ANIMATE these buttons in the process of transitioning to and fro the hamburger and back button icons?

Comment: You save my day! Nice solution! I'm build it in my app with fragments and it's works fine! Good job! +1

Comment: great, is there A way I can make a transition? It would improve the user experience a lot

Comment: Works very well! I only had to set the listener once, as the doc for setToolbarNavigationClickListener() says "when drawer indicator is disabled", so no need to unset and re-set later.

Comment: IMO, this is way too hacky and uncalled for... I will post a simpler solution.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli Will be interesting to see your solution. If it's better, then great. This solution is over a year old and I wouldn't be surprised if there's an 'easier' way :)

Comment: @ade.akinyede I posted it. Again, I don't see any use for the Toggle object. Also, another way to go is not use the home button at all, and simply add your own button the the action bar CustomView and handle events on it (and replacement of functionality/icon it when needed). Navigation drawer should really have better integration with the action bar

Comment: Nice! This should be a feature built into the Activity itself.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I seemed to have lost the action bar title though for some odd reason.

Comment: @Amos Did you call setTitle() in your Activity?

Comment: Yes, should I be doing that from the fragment?

Comment: You can do that as well - getActivity().setTitle("Title"), but depends on your implementation. And make sure you've called setSupportActionBar(mToolbar) in your activity.

Comment: Hi guys, where should I put the function: enableViews() ? Thanks

Comment: @ThânHoàng I would imagine in your activity, where you have the drawerLayout and toolbar

Comment: This solution worked for me after adding `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(0)` below `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` of the enable back button code branch in `enableViews` function.

Comment: This answer is very well rounded. Thank you sir!

Comment: Great solution! And it works with androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout, API level 25.
You can enable the back button and restore the burger at will while the normal behavior of the burger and drawer continue to work. You must replace the call to onBackPressed with something else that resets your conditions that made the back button to be active and the burger re-appears.

Answer (score 7):

The top solutions did not work in this case:

- One Activity and multiple Fragments
- One Fragment (SettingsFragment) should show the back icon instead of the burger menu
- Using com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout, androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar and ActionBarDrawerToggle

I call this method in my Activity's onCreate():

```
private fun initBackStackChangeListener() {
    supportFragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)

        if (fragment is SettingsFragment) {
            menuDrawerToggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = false
            drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
            menuDrawerToggle?.setToolbarNavigationClickListener { onBackPressed() }
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        } else {
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
            drawer_layout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
            menuDrawerToggle?.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = true
            menuDrawerToggle?.toolbarNavigationClickListener = null
            menuDrawerToggle?.syncState()
        }
    }
}
```

And menuDrawerToggle is this:

```
menuDrawerToggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer_layout, toolbar,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
        R.string.navigation_drawer_close
    ).apply {
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(this)
        this.syncState()
    }
```

Works like a charm. Maybe it helps anybody.

Answer (score 5):

I found flexible solutions in [The Google I/O 2017 Android App](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/e4364eec0d8f358215aee30cce2b4836ec169b5a/lib/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/BaseActivity.java#L330-L363).

```
public Toolbar getToolbar() {
    if (mToolbar == null) {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            mToolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(R.string.navdrawer_description_a11y);
            mToolbarTitle = (TextView) mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
            if (mToolbarTitle != null) {
                int titleId = getNavigationTitleId();
                if (titleId != 0) {
                    mToolbarTitle.setText(titleId);
                }
            }

            // We use our own toolbar title, so hide the default one
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    return mToolbar;
}

/**
 * @param clickListener The {@link android.view.View.OnClickListener} for the navigation icon of
 *                      the toolbar.
 */
protected void setToolbarAsUp(View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
    // Initialise the toolbar
    getToolbar();
    if (mToolbar != null) {
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_up);
        mToolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(R.string.close_and_go_back);
        mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(clickListener);
    }
}
```

So the usage is really simple.

```
setToolbarAsUp(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // onBackPressed();
        // or navigate to parent or some other intent
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

The selected answer is too hacky in my opinion.

I tried implementing it, and while doing so I realized that there's actually no good use for the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` (maybe that is why it was removed from the official android tutorial regarding [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer)): it doesn't make your life easier when you want to co-ordinate between the navigate drawer and the action bar.

The problem is that you only have 1 home "button", and that it has 2 different functionalities - **open the drawer** when you are in the main screen, and **go up** when you are further down in your app. Passing the toolbar as a parameter to `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor, adds the menu icon to it, and calls openDrawer on click event. Now if you want to switch to an up event you have to turn off this special icon, and re-enable the inherent back functionality of the action bar... which is still a mess.

So if `ActionBarDrawerToggle` doesn't help you (yet, maybe someone will figure out a way where it does), why use it in the first place? Here's how to do it without it:

```
boolean homeShouldOpenDrawer; // flag for onOptionsItemSelected

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // if you're using NoActionBar theme
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

    // enables the home button with a <-
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // replaces the <- with the menu (hamburger) icon 
    // (ic_menu should be in every empty project, and can be easily added)
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

    // I assume your first fragment/state should be main screen, i.e. home = opens drawer
    homeShouldOpenDrawer = true;
    ...
}

private void enableViews(boolean enable) {
    if(enable) {
        // Enables back button icon
        // passing null or 0 brings back the <- icon
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(null);
        homeShouldOpenDrawer = false;
    } else {
        // Enables burger icon
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        homeShouldOpenDrawer = true;
    }

}

// this is called whenever a selection is made from the action bar
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (homeShouldOpenDrawer) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                onBackPressed();
            }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Firstly, remove the name callout and negative approach in your post. It's anti-community. As a developer, it should be clear how quickly the eco-system changes, so will the solution(s).

Comment: there was no intention to offend you. I spent 2 days trying to reconcile your answer to the tutorial, and this is the conclusion I came up with. I could also be wrong and maybe there's a better way to do it.

Comment: also, I don't think it's your "fault", something is definitely missing in the eco-system for good connectivity between action bar an navigation drawer

Answer (score 3):

you can change the action bar button with:

```
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_button);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Martín Huergo. I am expecting to not provide the drawable icon, unless if it is a native android drawable

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying some of these examples on my App, but none of them seemed to work. I am using fragments and some of them must show the back option instead of home. Here is my implementation (in Kotlin):

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED)
    var actionBar = (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar
    actionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    var  toggle= (activity as MainActivity).drawerToggle
    toggle.isDrawerIndicatorEnabled = false
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener { v ->  activity.onBackPressed() }
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
    drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED)
    var actionBar = (activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar
    actionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
    var  toggle= (activity as MainActivity).drawerToggle
    toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener {null}
    toggle.syncState()
}
```

**NOTE:** these are the overridden onResume and onStop method inside the fragment.

**REMARK:** the *hamburger* icon will only show up if the toggle.syncState() method is called. I've been almost 24 hours figuring out why the home icon wasn't showing.

Hope my post can help someone.

Comment: The toggle.syncState() is crucial... Thank you for that tip!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
      toolbar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=#ffffff>" +     getString(R.string.print_s) + "</font>"));
      toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu_icon));
     toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             DetailActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.fav);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener()     {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
              item.setIcon(R.drawable.back_icon)
              return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Dinesh. Have you read my bounty description?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code of `style` `AppTheme` to your `activity's theme/style.xml` it will make your `hamburger icon` to `back icon` with `animation`.

**Condition** if you are using hamburger icon with `NavigationDrawer` and `AppCompatActivity/ActionBarActivity`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        </style>


<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

I hope it helps! or you just have to do it with drawable only.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794796/1841777)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I wanted to change the *Burger* icon by a *Back Arrow* icon on the left side of `Fragment`'s ActionBar as I am using a `Navigation Drawer`. Also Adding a *Menu* on the right side.

In **Main** Activity, it's already set - by default when Android Studio create the Navigation Drawer for me - like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();
```

The issue is how to customize the `ActionBar` in the `Fragment`, so when I go to the `Fragment` it shall show me the customized `ActionBar` and when the *Back Arrow* icon is clicked, it shall leave the fragment and the `ActionBar` should back to the first state.

In **Fragment** (*Complete Implementation*):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // To show the menu options
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    showActionBar(); // the method to change ActionBar
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // inflate the customized menu which already created in XML
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // add implementation when user select an item from the menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.option1:
            // do something
            return true;
        case R.id.option2:
            // do something
            return true;
        case R.id.option3:
            // do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void showActionBar() {
    // get the ToolBar from Main Activity
    final Toolbar toolbar = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // get the ActionBar from Main Activity
    final ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    // inflate the customized Action Bar View
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actionbar, null);

    if (actionBar != null) {
        // enable the customized view and disable title
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setCustomView(v);
        // remove Burger Icon
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);

        // add click listener to the back arrow icon
        v.findViewById(R.id.back).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // reverse back the show
                actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                //get the Drawer and DrawerToggle from Main Activity
                // set them back as normal
                DrawerLayout drawer = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        getActivity(), drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                        R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                // All that to re-synchronize the Drawer State
                toggle.syncState();
                // Implement Back Arrow Icon 
                // so it goes back to previous Fragment
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**fragment_actionbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ic_menu_back.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="459"
    android:viewportWidth="459">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ffffff"
        android:pathData="M178.5,140.25v-102L0,216.75l178.5,178.5V290.7c127.5,0,216.75,40.8,280.5,130.05C433.5,293.25,357,165.75,178.5,140.25z"/>
</vector>
```

**fragment_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/border_shadow">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:title="@string/show_profile"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:title="@string/report_pic"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/option3"
        android:title="@string/delete_pic"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

-> If you have a drawer on homeactivity and initalfragment you have to show the drawertoggle and after inner fragement you don't want to show the drawer behalf of drawer you have to show the back button and change the title of all fragement like this.

- make your actionbartoggle public in your activity.
- in your home fragment write this code.

  ```
  @Override

  public void onResume() 

  {
      super.onResume();

      ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");

      ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

      ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);}
  ```
- and in other fragments write this code :

  ```
       @Override
      public void onResume() 
  {     super.onResume();
          ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Account");
          ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
          ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      }
  ```
- and in your main activity write in on backpressed :

  ```
  @Override
      public void onBackPressed() 
      {
          if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {

              getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();

          } else {

              super.onBackPressed();

          }
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**I have the simplest solution for Kotlin Developers**

Just add this in your root activity where fragments resist

```
if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
  supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
  toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
      if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0) {
          super.onBackPressed()
      } else {
          supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
          drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
          toggle.syncState()
          drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
      }
  }
} else {
  supportActionBar!!.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)
  drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
  toggle.syncState()
}
```

Here, whenever `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` is set `true` , I am showing back button. and on cliking it, I am calling `super.onBackPressed()` which is similar to what your back button does!

Answer (score -1):

You can use following to show the back button instead of Navigation menu.

```
(activity as MainActivity).supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back)
```