# How to show different navigation icon for different fragments?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I have one requirement like for home fragment I want to show default navigation icon with title and for other fragments I want to use back button icon with title .
How Can I do that ?

Comment: I tried this but that didn't work for me.
I have a main activity and multiple fragments for different items.When I am in home fragment I want to show default navigation icon with title and for other fragments I want to use back button icon with title.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579799/android-switch-actionbar-back-button-to-navigation-button) .

Comment: Down vote due to duplicate question, there are a lot of posts answering this, just google it.

Comment: @ADM
Thanks for the link.Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

use this code in your fragment `onResume()`

```
((Toolbar)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar)) .setNavigationIcon (R.drawable.my_icon);
```