# Navigation drawer icon with the back arrow in toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

How to include back arrow icon with the navigation icon on some particular `fragments` of `NavigationDrawer`..? Is it possible to have both `NavigationDrawer` icon and back arrow icon ??

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

this line is for back arrow inside activity..

I want the the back arrow to be placed in certain `fragments` alone not in all `fragments`..

Comment: then you need to make custom toolbar in your fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Switch ActionBar Back Button to Navigation Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579799/android-switch-actionbar-back-button-to-navigation-button)

Comment: i have not tested it just try once , in fragment where you don't want back arrow call `getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

if you have used ActionBarDrawerToggle then add this line
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

Comment: is it possible to have both back arrow and nav icon ??