# Change arrow icon to hamburger icon

Tags: java, android

I need to change the arrow icon back to the hamburger icon.

In my case,

A particular section in my activity changes depending on network response. I implemented all network calls.

And On the successful response, I changed the fragments. Everything works fine.

Except one,

When I change fragments the hamburger icon change to the back arrow icon. I really don't need the back functionality or anything related to the back arrow.

I [tried to change it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579799/android-switch-actionbar-back-button-to-navigation-button). But can't solve it.

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
```

I know this is a silly question but I can't solve it. Please help.

Comment: How is the icon setting related to the fragment? I assume your back icon is the one in the activities actionbar?

Comment: In the navigation drawer activity. @Jantzilla