# Xamarin.Android: Switch View

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I have the default generated Navigation Drawer Template created by Visual Studio.
But how do I switch the View?
I don't want to use a new Activity, because I want that the Navigation stays.
Do you know how to change the Fragment or whatever it is? I have the content_main.xml und this should change, but I don't know how

Please check my [Github repo](https://github.com/kaaax0815/Weather.Xamarin) for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the code below.

**layout_SwitchView.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<include
    android:id="@+id/FirstLayout"
    layout="@layout/layout_sw_first"
    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<include
    android:id="@+id/SecondLayout"
    layout="@layout/layout_sw_second"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<include
    android:id="@+id/menu_bar"
    layout="@layout/layout_sw_menubar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_SW_first.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:text="First Layout" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**layout_SW_second.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**layout_SW_menubar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/FirstMenuItem"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/tab_graph"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="First"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/SecondMenuItem"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/tab_chat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>         
   
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/moreMenuItem"
        android:paddingTop="6dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/star_small"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false" />
        <TextView
            android:text="More"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity_SwitchView.cs:**

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout_SwitchView);
        LinearLayout FirstMenuItemLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.FirstMenuItem);
        LinearLayout SecondMenuItemLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SecondMenuItem);
        LinearLayout firstlayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.FirstLayout);
        LinearLayout secondlayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SecondLayout);
        FirstMenuItemLayout.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            firstlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            secondlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        };


        SecondMenuItemLayout.Click += (sender, args) =>
        {
            firstlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            secondlayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        };
    }
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your work, but I couldn't figure it out how to transport this into my app. Could you please see my github repo (now in the question), so i have a answer that works with my code

Comment: I have checked your sample code. But what do you want to do the navigation? With the hamburger icon? If yes, you could check the sample in the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64640872/11850033

Comment: Yes, in my example i have a item in the drawer called "Chart" and if i click on that i want to change to another fragment

Comment: You could change your layout. For example, you have Three drawers named Weather, Grid and Chart. It matched three layous layout_Weather, layout_Grid, layout_Chart. Use the include to put the three layous in the main layout. And then use the Visibility to show the macthing layouts with the matching drawers.

Comment: Yes, i forget the mark to answer. Thanks alot